# Making other applications window's translucent in Delphi

Tags: windows, delphi, delphi-xe, lazarus, translucency

Good Day all

I searched the web for any directions as to if this is possible but to no avail. I need to write an application that will allow me to select another application and by doing so make the selected application translucent and on-top (like a ghost image overlay).

Is this at all possible with Delphi? I am using Delphi XE and Lazarus. If anybody could just please point me in the general direction of where to start I will be much obliged.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this *but is not recommended*, because this kind of behavior must be handled by the own application.  anyway if you insist because **do you have a very good reason to do this**, here i leave the code to set the transparency of a window and Make a windows Top Most, just to show how can be done.

**Transparency**

you must use the [`SetWindowLong`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633591%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function with the `WS_EX_LAYERED` flag and the [`SetLayeredWindowAttributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633540%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function with `LWA_ALPHA` to set the transparency.

```
Procedure SethWndTrasparent(hWnd: HWND;Transparent:boolean);
var
 l        : Longint;
 lpRect   : TRect;
begin
    if Transparent then
    begin
      l := GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE);
      l := l or WS_EX_LAYERED;
      SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, l);
      SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hWnd, 0, 180, LWA_ALPHA);
    end
    else
    begin
      l := GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE);
      l := l xor WS_EX_LAYERED;
      SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, l);
      GetWindowRect(hWnd, lpRect);
      InvalidateRect(hWnd, lpRect, true);
    end;
end;
```

**Make a windows Top Most**

You must use the [`SetWindowPos`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function passing the `HWND_TOPMOST`  value which places the window above all non-topmost windows. The window maintains its topmost position even when it is deactivated.

```
Procedure SethWndOnTop(hWnd: HWND);
var
  lpRect   : TRect;
begin
  if GetWindowRect(hWnd,lpRect) then
  SetWindowPos(hWnd , HWND_TOPMOST, lpRect.left, lpRect.top, lpRect.Right-lpRect.left, lpRect.Bottom-lpRect.Top, SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
end;
```

Answer (score 3):

Windows can do this but an app has got no hope of doing this robustly.

Comment: What you're asking for sounds like a way to force glass or alpha blending on another form.  Both would have problems and glitches, as David said. Maybe on Linux, if you hacked on the source code to Gnome3 and X11 (x.org) enough, you might be able to do this, but not on Windows.